# pass the value for key in dictionary as parameter

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

I have the below code:

```
def funct(start, end):
    perform some function
        yield(output)
    yield output

def param(start, end):
    for d in funct(start, end):
        dict = {"a": 123,"b": 456, "c": {start}, "d": {end}}
```

in the above, I want to pass the argument value **start, end** as value to the key in dictionary

how can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean? What's wrong with `dict = {"a": 123,"b": 456, "c": start, "d": end}`?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman the value of start, end will be given as input, i.e. some numeric value

Comment: Yes, and you want to put that numeric value into the dictionary, right? That's what `dict = {"a": 123,"b": 456, "c": start, "d": end}` do

Comment: Write str(start)

Comment: As explained by @TedKleinBergman, if you just put the variable name as value (without `{ }`), python will convert the variable to the actual value at run time. Hence `start = 6`, `{ "c": start}`, will be `{ "c": 6}`. Also you can use key word arguments, to pass values to functions using the arguments as key. In any case `my_dict = {"start": 6, "end":5}` and `func(**my_dict)`. Will read as `func(start=6, end=5)`.